# Delete rows from table recursively using JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I want to write a recursive function that will delete rows from my table.

I have the number of rows to keep and after that number i want to remove all rows.

for example:
I have the number 5 so the first 5 rows need to stay and the rest need to go. (using the row id)

code:

```
<table id="table">
<tr id="tr1"/>
<tr id="tr2"/>
<tr id="tr3"/>
<tr id="tr4"/>
<tr id="tr5"/>
<tr id="tr6"/>
<tr id="tr7"/>
<tr id="tr8"/>
</table>
```

I dont know how much rows i will have, thats why i think i need a recursive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several different jQuery filter approaches:

```
var numRows=5;
$('#table tr').slice(numRows).remove();
```

OR

```
$('#table tr:gt(' + (numRows-1) + ')').remove();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r4558914/)**</kbd>

References:

[slice() docs](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

[:gt() selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var deleteAfter =  5
$.each($("#table tr"),function(key,value){
    //do your conditional here
    if(key > deleteAfter-1){
        value.remove();
    }
});

alert("now the table row is "+$("#table tr").length);
```

});

This is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/9zdjt77g/2/)

I'm sorry if u want to using id as the input please use this instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //define the id first
    var deleteAfter = $("#tr5");
    var elementNo;

$.each($("#table tr"), function (key, value) {
    if (this.id == deleteAfter.attr("id")){
        elementNo = key;
    }
});

$.each($("#table tr"), function (key, value) {
    //do your conditional here
    if (key > elementNo) {
        value.remove();
    }
});

alert("now the table row is " + $("#table tr").length);
});
```

And i updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/9zdjt77g/3/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use :gt() selector, it selects all the elements greater than index and then you can remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = 4; // set index 4, so want to remove 5 elements( 0 to 4)
    $('#table tr:gt('+index+')').remove();
});
```